# Gitian Build Issue - Windows

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, development

Got a little issue when compiling Windows QT using Gitian. BTW Im using a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit VPS.

So I am using the instructions here : https://cryptocointalk.com/topic/2966-bitcoin-scrypt-v120-source-code-and-compile-instructions-for-linux-windows-and-mac/?p=25594

Everything works pretty much fine until step 20 (sudo bin/gbuild ../bitcoin/contrib/gitian-descriptors/qt-win32.yml)

When I get this error :

************* WARNING: kvm not loaded, this will probably not work out

--- Building for lucid i386 ---
Stopping target if it is up
Making a new image copy
qemu-img: Could not open 'base-lucid-i386.qcow2'
bin/gbuild:21:in `system!': failed to run make-clean-vm --suite lucid --arch i386 (RuntimeError)
        from bin/gbuild:57:in`build_one_configuration'
        from bin/gbuild:235
        from bin/gbuild:230:in `each'
        from bin/gbuild:230
        from bin/gbuild:228:in`each'
        from bin/gbuild:228

What am I doing wrong ?

BTW step two did not go so well either : ls -l /dev/kvm did not return anything but I suspect it wasn't anything too important and other steps worked fine until this.

Comment: The first line of your error states that kvm is not loaded. The command `ls -l /dev/kvm` checks the dev/kvm device and shows nothing. There is your problem. Do you meet the requirements?

Comment: Hi, as far as i know it needs to be a 64 bit ubuntu. This VPS im using is Ubuntu 12.04 and is a 64 bit vm. Am I missing something ? is their any way to load the kvm ?